# WPF Window Title binding base on Information Class?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have Wpf-App for working on person object. Person Struct is  Sql-server table and I use Linq-to-Sql for my project(so there is class in dbml refer to person).

I have form for update or inserting persons(simple modal window). In this window I have `Peoperty` which have current value of person.

```
public Person CurrentPerson { get; set; }
```

So what I look for is :

> How bind title of this window base on `CurrentPerson.FullName`? and absolutely Window Title must change if CurrentPerson.FullName Changed!

**Edit: More Info**
I want to change window title base on `CurrentPerson.Name` not set equally same as `CurrentPerson.Name`. So this might be change something. Also I searched before find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511053/wpf-data-binding-window-title-to-view-model-property) and this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667511/binding-only-part-of-a-label) about changing part of Title. but I need to change some part of Title base on value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your codebehind or viewmodel should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. After that, implement a property `WindowTitle` like this:

```
public string WindowTitle 
{ 
    get { return "Some custom prefix" + CurrentPerson.FullName; } 
}
```

After this, whenever your change the `FullName` on your `CurrentPerson`, just throw a `PropertyChanged` event, for example:

```
Person _currentPerson;
public Person CurrentPerson 
{
    get { return _currentPerson; }
    set
    {
        _currentPerson = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("WindowTitle"));
    }
}
```

EDIT: Please post your xaml code for the binding, which looking at your comment on the post of Novice, seems like the culprit. Also, check that you are setting the `Window`'s `DataContext` to itself.

Comment: Thanks I don't set `DataContext` for current window. after setting it worked well .

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: Deleted the old answer because I completely misunderstood the question.

The problem is likely to be in your binding. I think the binding fails because it cant decide where to search for `CurrentUser(binding source)`. Can you try this -

**Edit 2:** You can name your control and then use that name in Binding Element, like:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="{Binding ElementName=MW,Path=CurrentUser.FullName, StringFormat='Welcome \{0\}!'}"        
    Name="MW">
```

If this doesn't work can you enable WPF debugging for binding expressions by going to:

`Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window -> WPF Trace Settings` [this is for VS2010; should be similar for others.]

and check if there is a binding error and if so what it is.

Comment: @Rev:Oh I missed the Linq-to-Sql bit. That will explain the down vote (which is fine). I hope I understood the issue now.

Comment: @Rev: didn't know whether you were using a custom control for a title bar or the regular standard window.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Person _currentPerson;
public Person CurrentPerson 
{
    get { return _currentPerson; }
    set
    {
        _currentPerson = value;
        this.Title = value.FullName;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rev I'd like to see if someone can either do this, or explain why it's not possible.  It seems normal binding methods don't work in this case, but I don't know why.

Comment: Yes I try even dependency prop or convertor but I can't do this. I don't know how to do this, maybe someone can help me!